# Truncated in-line labels on Horizontal Bar

Tags: vue.js, chart.js, vue-chartjs

I am using `vue-chartjs` with the `datalabels` plugin activated. Labels are aligned at the end.

As you can see on the screenshot below, top labels can end up cut by the canvas. The parameters are below. I tried to switch `responsive` and `maintainAspectRatio` to false, but no success.

Is it expected behavior or a bug?

```
responsive: true,
maintainAspectRatio: true,
plugins: {
    datalabels: {
        display: true,
        color: 'black',
        anchor: 'end',
        align: 'end',
        offset: 1
    }
}
```

[image: Example of an overflow]